# Toggling visibility of series of images: pie_1.png, bar_1.png, pie_2.png, bar_2.png

Tags: jquery

I have [webpages](http://preferans.de/user.php?id=OK455973319345) with several (and more is coming) types of data, each represented by a bar and a pie Google chart image:

```
<h3>Data_1</h3>
<p class="chart" align="center">
<img class="primary" src="pie_1.png">
<img class="secondary" src="bar_1.png">
</p>

<h3>Data_2</h3>
<p class="chart" align="center">
<img class="primary" src="pie_2.png">
<img class="secondary" src="bar_2.png">
</p>

....
```

Initially I'd like to display pie-charts and hide bar-charts.

When user clicks a pie-chart, I'd like to toggle it to bar-chart with [a slide effect](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/).

I think, I have a good idea how to do it with jQuery - using individual ids like **#pie_1**, **#bar_1**, **#pie_2**, **#bar_2**, ...

But I wonder, if a more general approach is possible here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and the [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) jQuery methods, like this:

```
bars.click(function () {
    $(this).slideUp().next().slideDown();
});
pies.click(function () {
    $(this).slideUp().prev().slideDown();
});
```